# Approximating differentiable function by smooth one with "metric norm" not affected much

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> On a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ , we have a function $\psi : M \to \Bbb R$, which is *differentiable*, and furthermore satisfies some "small derivative" condition as follows : if we consider the one-form given by $d\psi$, then since $g$ is a metric, the quantity $g(d\psi,d\psi) := (||d\psi||_g)^2$ makes sense and is an element of $\mathbb R$. I am asked to assume that $||d\psi||_g \leq \frac 14$.
>
> From here I would like to find a **smooth** function $\psi_0 : M \to \Bbb R$ such that $|\psi - \psi_0| \leq 1$ and $||d\psi_0||_g \leq 1$.

My first approach to this problem was to seek a solution for Euclidean space with the Euclidean inner product. Here, I see only convolution with a suitable mollifier at some point as a solution. But can this even be carried over to a manifold?

Furthermore, I do  not quite know how a small change in the function changes $d\psi$ and therefore $||d\psi||_g$, so my ability to attack this problem is just about as blunt as it gets.

EDIT 1 : For further context, this is part of an exercise which is used to prove an extension of the Hopf-Rinow theorem (there is a version which includes two more conditions than the usual, and is apparently useful in the field of several complex variables to prove one of their "big" theorems, the name of which I don't happen to know unfortunately).

EDIT 2 : Nash's embedding theorem tells us that without loss of generality we can assume that $(M,g)$ is just a submanifold of some Euclidean space with the restriction of the Euclidean metric, but I don't want to use this.

Comment: When you convolve a differentiable $\psi$ with a mollifier $\eta$, you have $(\psi * \eta)' =\psi' * \eta;$ so the approximation $(\psi * \eta)' \approx\psi'$ is just as good as the approximation $\psi *  \eta \approx \psi$. To carry the mollification technique over to manifolds, the usual approach is to approximate the function in each chart of an atlas and then glue the results together using a partition of unity.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I see. However, can you elaborate a little more about the "metric norm" in this context? So it should go via creating local functions and then gluing them together. The  question then arises : a partition of unity need not have very regular functions,so during the gluing, is it possible that the metric norm factor may not be in control?

Comment: If you multiply by the partition of unity *before* you mollify, it turns out not to be a problem. There is an issue with the norm: obviously the metric norm and the Euclidean norm do not agree. When you're working on a compact domain, the norms are uniformly comparable so this isn't an issue. In general you need to first multiply by a cutoff function (say, the indicator of $\bar B_R (x_0)$) to make the function compactly supported, do the approximation, and then let $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis This looks good, I think. Thank you for your help, but if I am stumbling I'll get back.